# Bootstrap Carousel auto-scrolls whole page when changing slides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to add a bootstrap carousel to our existing website www.121studios.ca. Currently the carousel works fine except the page scrolls up so that the carousel lines up with the top of the browser. I think it has something do to with the navbar and the way it auto-scrolls to a section that you select.

https://jsfiddle.net/zocpu8oo/5/

This is the code for navbar, I'm not sure why it scrolls even though the carousel section isn't included. (quick note: the carousel is between the about section and membership section if that makes a different)

(before I click next)
[image]

(after I click next)
[image]

```
<header id="header" class="light">
    <!-- Logo: Delete "class="logo"" to remove the logo or upload your own logo to "assets/images". -->
    <a id="logo" href="#intro"></a>

    <!-- Navigation: Each item below must correspond with the "section" id's defined below. -->
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="current"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu">Membership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="http://121studios.tumblr.com">Blog</a></li> -->
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: okay, so you're navigating your navbar but it performs the same actions as a carousel? on the fiddle i don't seem to find a carousel or a navbar

Comment: Fiddle doesn't have a bootstrap resource thing but I'll try my best to show you with pictures 

(before I click next) http://imgur.com/Om3eZtp

(after I click next) http://imgur.com/cyNHWLh

Comment: it does, add jquery 2.1 + and the drop down box below it will give you the option for jquery mobile, boostrap on the left hand side of jsfiddle

Comment: Oh whoops I didn't know that, sorry. I updated it but everything is very messy still. Would it be possible/allowed if I uploaded the site files and let people open it up themselves?

Comment: try the answer already given by darren sweeney, it seems workable.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the navigation is `position: fixed` - if you add say `margin-top: 100px` to `#intro` it works as planned

Comment: I tried what you said but no luck. Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: Go here, it works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/zocpu8oo/1/ added one css class at the end of your css

Comment: Oh that's strange. It does work fine in jsfiddle but when I added that in my own file on my computer it still does the scrolling. I've opened up the file in chrome and firefox so I don't think it's a browser problem.